# Extracting values from Pig job

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am dealing with the output of a Pig job which is in the following format:

```
((a,b,c),2014-12-27)
((a,b,c1),2014-12-27)
```

I want this result:

```
(a,b,c,2014-12-27)
(a,b,c1,2014-12-27)
```

I have tried using `GENERATE FLATTEN` and `GENERATE`, but the first three fields are still grouped together.

Comment: Flatten should work. Please explore more and check your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume that r1 relation contains the below

```
((a,b,c),2014-12-27)
((a,b,c1),2014-12-27)
```

We can achieve flatten by using below statement

```
r2 = FOREACH r1 GENERATE FLATTEN($0) AS(a1,a2,a3),$1;
dump r2;
```

Comment: Thanks Surender, but here is the issue i have. I did try flatten but it throws a null pointer when i go by your suggestion. The reason is when i do a DESCRIBE on the loaded dataset i get the following:A: {c1: char array,c2: char array,c3: char array,c4: char array}. But when i do a DUMP the result of that dump is how i have shown in my question and not what i would expect which would be (c1,c2,c3,c4).

Comment: To give more context, the input set i am working with is a UNION of 3 result sets which are created as :H3 = FOREACH G3 GENERATE group, MIN(F3.c4) and then res = UNION H1, H2, H3. Hence what i get is a group (set of keys) and an aggregate.

Comment: Thanks Surender a bunch for giving me that idea. What i did was applied that logic to the parent job and made it spit out a flattened structure which i then read in my subsequent job without any issues.